# blazor.server.js breaks my script files in my Blazer Web App project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-client-side

These are my files and I tried to import my files by using OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender) , but after I've executed my application,I didn't see my files in the "view page source" in the browser.

This is my code please :-

**_Host.chtml (Head Section)**

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Test</title>
    <base href="~/" />

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/allinone_bannerRotator.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script>
        jQuery(function () {

            jQuery('#allinone_bannerRotator_universal').allinone_bannerRotator({
                skin: 'universal',
                width: 893,
                height: 496,
                responsive: true,
                thumbsWrapperMarginBottom: -35,
                showNavArrows: false,
                showCircleTimer: false,
                showCircleTimerIE8IE7: false,
                autoHideBottomNav: false,
                showPreviewThumbs: false
            });
        });

    </script>

</head>
```

**_Host.chtml (BodySection)**

```
<body>
<script src="_framework/blazor.server.js"></script> 
</body>
```

**MainLayout.razor **

```
@code {
    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        if (firstRender)
        {     
            await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>("import", "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js");
            await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>("import", "./Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js");
            await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>("import", "./Scripts/jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js");
            await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>("import", "./Scripts/allinone_bannerRotator.js");

        }
    }
}
```

**Note :- When I move blazor.server.js  from body to head , everything working fine.
Could anyone helps me please ?**